# How to use MultiView as Tabs in Asp.net 2.0?

Tags: asp.net

How to use MultiView as Tabs in Asp.net 2.0? Is there a good example available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/custom-controls/TabControl.aspx

Answer (score 1):

[The ajax toolkit](http://www.asp.net/(S(vovsvx454o5rex452c4ypcy3))/ajax/) has a tab control which will allow this (well very similar) behaviour.

Failing that, look into jQuery to do this.